# React.js with Create React App —— what can i do with config-overrides.js to load js files only when they are needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

when run in localhost or when i build in prodution, i find that when i open my website, all js files are loaded,but many of them i do not need, and sometimes get errors that show Loading chunk.js failed, what should I do with config-overrides.js like webpack.config.js ? I need to make js files load when they are needed. And my project is a big project
Thanks

[image]

I didn't find information's about this

And I check my index.html and find that it builds chunk.js with **rel** **prefecth**